# WebRTC no video in different network

Tags: node.js, github, socket.io, webrtc

Sorry about my English. I have a problem with webRTC. My application works correctly in the same network but in different is wrong.

Technologies that I use:

- socket.io
- node
- coffeescript
- gulp
- [zenserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zenserver)

In this github I push my code: [github/oihi08/webrtc](https://github.com/oihi08/webrtc)

I dont know why the application not runs with different networks. I have uploaded to a server, I tried it and nothing. But in the same network yes.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: We need more information here. Can the different networks accept the connection (firewalls, NAT, etc.), are you using a TURN Server that is properly setup and formatted, etc.

Comment: Is your socket for messaging always "localhost:8080"? How is a remote client going to connect to your server for messaging?

Comment: I also tested with sockets on a server and not works. I not know so much about this topic, I am learning about WebRTC.

Comment: I need to build an "application" with webRTC in different network. I am studying and researching but I do not get it on different networks

Comment: @oihi08 I know this question is old, but have you managed to solve this problem? I'm using node, I set a STUN and TURN server, but its still intermittent, sometimes works, sometimes not! Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you aren't using a STUN/TURN server. There are a few steps to create a connection between two devices. One of these steps is to select one or more STUN/TURN servers (like "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" for example). This server will be used to create a connection between peers, even when there is a firewall in the way on one or both ends.

When you set up one or more STUN/TURN servers, you will see that ice candidates will start being generated. The callback function `peerConnection.onicecandidate` will be called for every ice candidate that is generated. When the library is done generating ice candidates, it calls the callback one more time with `NULL` as parameter, this flags the end of the list of candidates.

You need to get these ice candidates across to the other peer somehow, usually through the same signaling server you use to create the connection in the first place. When they arrive at the other side you need to call peerconnection.addIceCandidate.

If you do these steps, you will be able to get a proper connection, even across networks with strict NAT types.

Comment: If you just look at the posted source code, you will see that he is using a TON of STUN servers.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent If you just read my answer, you will see that he needs a TURN server as well. He is also not sending his ICE candidates nor is he setting them on the other side.

Comment: It looks to me like he is handling `onicecandidate` and signalling through...unless that logic does not work in coffee script.

Comment: Maybe not works with coffeescript... I am going to try it in javascript

Comment: I tried it with TURN server (http://www.turnservers.com/) and not works.. The updated code is in Github. Thank you!!

Comment: @oihi08 Can you inspect the ice candidates you receive? Ice candidates are used to negotiate how the connection will be established, you should get at least 4 or 5, but probably more. If a firewall is blocking the p2p connection there should be "relay" ice candidates in there with the ip-address of your TURN server. The connection will then go via this TURN server instead of p2p. If all of that goes well and you still can't get a connection, it's not firewall-related. If you have two routers, you can also create two separate subnets and see if you can get a connection across those two networks

Comment: @lorenzo373 I have put a log in onicecandidate function and it returns this logs:
RTCIceCandidateEvent {candidate: RTCIceCandidate, clipboardData: undefined, path: NodeList[0], cancelBubble: false, returnValue: true…}

This returns in 5 times